# How to response 404 http status code corresponding redirect to custome 404 page in Razor pages?

Tags: http-status-code-404, .net-6.0, razor-pages, http-redirect, c#-10.0

> Blockquote

In my case, I get a permalink in OnGet() method behind of my cshtml page, and lookup in data base if the permalink has record or not. If true the proper page will return but if false I want to send http status code 404 and then redirect to a custom 404 page with 200 http code status.
Please mention that, I don't want to redirect with permanent 301 or temporary 302 status codes. It's Important to reponse 404 status code then redirect with 200 status code.
So how it could be achived in Asp.net Core Razor pages(.Net6)
I'll be appriciated if there is any help code or advice.
Here is a screenshot for desire result form of this redirection with status code.
[image: Status code 404 redirection]

Comment: Once you've returned a 404 status code, you can't send another response.

Comment: @MikeBrindI I just wants to redirect after 404, and redirection page will show 200 by itself. But not to want 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the HttpContext StatusCode response to 404

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
  {
      HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
      //Or
      HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;

      return Page();
  }
```